# Xaml markup extension not found

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms app I am trying to set the source of an Embedded Image in one of my xaml files but when creating the custom namespace I get the error
`Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 31:12. MarkupExtension not found for local:ImageResource`.  I am basing it on the official documentation at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images and have also checked out the sample code.  My assembly name and default namespace both match that in the xaml file.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows.  I have had someone else to try the code on Xamarin Studio on a Mac and the code works fine and the image displays.

xaml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App;assembly=App"
         x:Class="App.LoginPage">

 <RelativeLayout>

    <Label Text="Logo"
       RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
       RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.3}" BackgroundColor="Aqua" />

    <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="20"
       VerticalOptions="Center"
       RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
       RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.5}"
       RelativeLayout.XConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0}"
       RelativeLayout.YConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.3}">

      <Entry Placeholder="Username"
         Text="{Binding Username}"/>
      <Entry Placeholder="Password"
         Text="{Binding Password}"
         IsPassword="true"/>
      <Button Text="Login" TextColor="White"
          BackgroundColor="Blue"
          Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>

    </StackLayout>

    <Image Source="{local:ImageResource App.logo.png}"
       Aspect="AspectFill"
       RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.4}"
       RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.15}"
       RelativeLayout.XConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.6}"
       RelativeLayout.YConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.85}" />

 </RelativeLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you get this error when you build or run your project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because there is no built-in type converter from string to ResourceImageSource, these types of images cannot be natively loaded by Xaml.

To get around this restriction, a simple custom Xaml markup extension can be written to load images using a Resource ID specified in Xaml.

```
[ContentProperty ("Source")]
public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
 { 
  public string Source { get; set; }

  public object ProvideValue (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
 {
   if (Source == null)
   return null;

  // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
  var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source);

  return imageSource;
 }
}
```

To use this extension add a custom xmlns to the Xaml, using the correct namespace and assembly values for the project. The image source can then be set using this syntax: {local:ImageResource WorkingWithImages.beach.jpg}

[Source](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images)

Comment: Thanks, I now see the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Dakshal's answer should be correct however one thing that might be missing is that the markup extension needs to reside in the same namespace/assembly that you are pointing to in your xmlns alias. So be sure that this code exists in your forms project:

```
namespace App
{
    [ContentProperty ("Source")]
    public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (Source == null)
                return null;

            // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source);

            return imageSource;
        }
    }
}
```

It is important that the namespace (`App` in this example) matches your alias designated in the XAML file (`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App;assembly=App"` in this case).

The documentation does not point this out. It assumes that you know to correlate the namespace alias with the CLR namespace that you place the extension code in.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just do:

```
<Image Source="logo.png"/>
```

This will look for the image in the following directories:

**Android:** Resources\drawable

**iOS:** Resources

**UWP:** basefolder

See more [here (Working with images in Xamarin)](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Local_Images)

Comment: this requires having a copy of each image in each project.  Embedded images allow you to have once copy of the image in the PCL only

Comment: @Jason What would you say is the advantage of having a single copy in the PCL project? I can see advantages of keeping them in the native projects (the main one being you can use each platform's auto sizing mechanism). When you build the app, you only build a specific platform, you won't actually get 2,3,5 copies of each image, just the ones you actually need and use. so what is the advantage of having them embedded in the PCL?

Comment: Ease of maintenance.  If you have 30 images, and your customer gives you updated artwork to use, are you going to have to update 1 project, or 3?

Answer (score -1):

just add `[ContentProperty("Source")]` before your Markup class. like:

`[ContentProperty("Source")]
    public class EmbeddedImage : IMarkupExtension
    {
      //................
    }`